# Non Programmer can't obtain sub query with aggregated sum

Tags: sql

I have 2 queries that I need to link together on one line:

```
SELECT pvp.part_no, pvp.name,
    Max(convert(varchar(10), pc.recalc_date, 101)) as 'Previous Cost Date',
    Max(pc.cost) as 'Previous Cost',
    Min(convert(varchar(10),pc2.recalc_date, 101)) as 'Latest Cost Date',
    Min (pc2.cost) as 'Latest Cost'
FROM part_v_part as pvp
JOIN part_v_part_cost as pc ON pvp.part_key = pc.part_key
Left outer join part_v_part_cost as pc2 on
pvp.part_key = pc2.part_key and
pc2.recalc_date > pc.recalc_date
Join part_v_container pvc on pc.part_key = pvc.part_key
WHERE pvp.part_status <> 'inactive'
AND pvp.part_status <> 'obsolete'       
AND pc2.recalc_date between '1/01/2017' and '1/31/2017'
AND pvc.active = 1
AND pvc.container_status = 'OK'
AND pvp.part_no = '90-0018'
GROUP BY pvp.part_no, pvp.name, pvp.part_key

-- =====================================================================

SELECT PVP1.Part_No AS 'Part No',
    PVp1.Name AS 'Description', 
    PVP1.Revision AS 'Rev',
    SUM(pvc1.quantity ) AS 'QOH at cost update'
FROM Part_V_Container pvc1
JOIN Part_V_Part pvp1 ON pvc1.Part_Key = pvp1.Part_Key
WHERE pvc1.active = 1
AND pvc1.container_status = 'OK'
AND pvc1.add_date <= '1/6/17'
AND pvp1.part_no = '90-0018' 
GROUP BY PVP1.Part_No,PVP1.Name, PVP1.Revision
```

Below are the results of my 2 queries. I need to integrate the QOH at cost update field from the 2nd query into the 1st query.
I've have spent days researching this and I keep ending up with errors like sub-queries cannot contain aggregate functions.

Making matters worse is the sql tool I am using is embedded into an ERP system so I have no idea what version of SQL is being used. The best I can tell is TSQL?

```
part_no | name                     | Previous Cost Date | Previous Cost | Latest Cost Date  | Latest Cost
1       | 90-0018   PISTON, DRIVEN | 07/19/2016         |  28.93685     | 01/06/2017        | 39.16178
```

Row Count: 1

Part No Description Rev QOH at cost update

1   90-0018 PISTON, DRIVEN  A   51.00000
Row Count: 1

Comment: How do you want to match the results from the 2nd query to the 1st query? They are grouped on different fields, and so may not match 1-to-1. Do you just want to match them up by part number?

Comment: There should be a column or a group of columns that can be used to "integrate" the data. Is part_no sufficient?

Comment: Yes, I want to match them by the part number.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand the need, you have to:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
Paste first query here
) a
JOIN
(
Paste second query here
) b
ON a.part_no = b.[Part No]
```

This will give you all the columns of both queries joined using the part_no value

Hope this helps

Comment: I'm so close now! I'm getting the following msg:  The following errors occurred during execution of the SQL query:

Invalid column name 'part_no'.

Comment: @LeRoyMurphy you should probably upvote the answer if you found it useful. Thanks!